# Не могу вывести значения коллекции в словаре c#

Tags: c#, словари, коллекции

Есть уже заполненный словарь Dictionary<int, List> group = new Dictionary<int, List>();
Не могу вывести поочерёдно значения ключа и коллекций. Не пойму, как это делать. Мой способ не работает. Должно выглядеть как (например) Группа 1 Значения: 2, 3, 5, 7...

```
foreach(int k  in group.Keys)
{
    Console.Write($"Группа {k} Значения: ");
    foreach(var v in group.Values)
    {
        Console.Write($"{v} ");
    }
    Console.WriteLine();
}
```

Comment: Что то типа `foreach(var kv in group){ … foreach(var v in kv.Value) {…}}` точность не гарантирую, набираю с телефона, но идея понятна

Comment: Ну или `group[k]` вместо `group.Values` использовать

Comment: @АндрейNOP так даже проще, хоть и чууууть чуууууть медленней =)

Answer (score 0):

Тебе нужно пары ключ-значение перебирать:

```
foreach (var g in group)
{
    Console.Write($"Группа {g.Key} Значения: ");
    foreach(var v in g.Values)
    {
        Console.Write($"{v.Value} ");
    }
    Console.WriteLine();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Вот так правильно:

```
foreach (var k  in group)
{
    Console.Write($"Группа {k.Key} Значения: ");
    foreach(var v in k.Value)
    {
        Console.Write($"{v} ");
    }
    Console.WriteLine();
}
```